# Use final on traits in PHP

Tags: php, oop, traits

What i want is the ability to make "final traits" with the behaviour as described below. I realise this is not possible with traits(or is it? that would make me so happy), but I'm just trying to convey what I want to do.

So, i want to have a trait that is

```
trait Content {
    public final function getPostContent(){ /*...*/ }
    public final function setPostContent($content){ /*...*/ }
}
```

What I want is

Marking the functions in the traits as final making sure that if a class uses this trait, the trait implementation is the guaranteed implementation

```
class MyClass {
    use Content;
    public function getPostContent() { // This should not be allowed
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to somehow check if a class uses a trait(i.e. $myObject instanceof Content)

```
class MyClass {}
class MyClassWithContent {
    use Content;
}
var_dump((new MyClass) instanceof Content); // "bool(false)"
var_dump((new MyClassWithContent) instanceof Content; // "bool(true)"
```

Making sure that when the trait is being used, the methods name/visibility can not be changed. So, none of this should be allowed.

```
class MyDeceptiveClass {
    use Content {
        Content::getPostContent as nowItsNotCalledGetPostContentAnymore();
        Content::setPostContent as protected; // And now setPostContent is protected
    }
}
```

Comment: The age old question: how can I prevent people who can access the source code from doing things that I don't want them to? The short story is "you can't", and you have to learn to accept that. In terms of "type hinting" a trait, your better option is to use an interface that the trait implements.

Comment: Of course, in many cases you can. I would argue that that is one of the strengths of strong typed languages for instance, and an effect of a good class design. But thanks though, I didn't know traits could implement interfaces.

Comment: As another note: python (as an example) doesn't have a concept of `public` and `private` because it, as a language, accepted that if people can extend your code, they can replace/modify/update your code. I see those keywords as being more suggestive than actually restrictive. They're helpful for determining program flow, but not so helpful for actually preventing skullduggery.

Comment: Highly disagree, all languages I have used with a private and public keyword also has protected and final(as php does) which solves that problem. Private is not available outside the class no matter what, protected is available for subclasses, public is available for everyone, final classes can not be overwritten.

Comment: Using traits isn't inheritance. As I've understood it, when using "use" in a class to use a trait, the compiler more or less "copy/paste" the trait into your class. That means that you can't check if a class uses a trait since it's not an instance of the trait.

Comment: [ReflectionClass::getTraits()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraits.php)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the 'trait/interface' thing, traits can't directly implement interfaces (I wish they could), but you would say that the class implements the interface, and use the trait in the class. See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UWrTeiPm)

Comment: That is a good idea, but gives no guarantee of the implementation(no guarantee that the getPostContent() is the correct implementation of getPostContent). I want to be able to, somehow, check that the implementation is the one in the trait(i.e. I really really want final methods in traits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods in traits are overwritten by methods defined in a class, even if the trait method is `final`:

```
<?php
trait Bar {
    final public function fizz() {
        echo "buzz\n";
    }
}

class Baz {
    use Bar;

    public function fizz() {
        echo "bam\n";
    }
}

$x = new Baz;
$x->fizz(); // bam
```

Taking a look at the [precedence section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence) in the traits documentation:

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

Comment: Well, that defeats the purpose of defining a method in a trait final. 

Comment: Not really. Traits _aren't_ inheritance - they're more like mixins. You're not _re-defining_ a method in that trait, you're just _not using_ the method from the trait (because it's already defined in your class)

The only place where traits _kind of_ behave like inheritance is property definitions. You can't have different property definitions in a trait and a class which uses the trait (e.g. if a trait defines `public string $foo = 'bar';` your class can't define `public string $foo = 'baz';`, or otherwise alter the definition of `$foo`) - don't ask me why that is.