# Sharing constants between two base classes

Tags: php

How would you share constants between two bases classes?

Traits don't allow constants and that was my first instinct. I don't want to define them on the config files because they're not meant to be shared by the whole application.

Comment: Create a parent class with your constants and extend this class by those 2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular solution I ended up creating an Interface with the constants and implementing it on the base classes that needed them.

Look at this question for a reference:

[PHP Traits - defining generic constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357985/php-traits-defining-generic-constants)